# JSONObject to String returns null (with valid JSON)

Tags: java, null, tostring, json

I am facing the following difficulty:
I create a JSONObject.
With `System.out.println (finalJson)` I get the output below. It is valid JSON according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). But when I try to get the String representationn by calling `finalJson.toString ()`, it only returns null. How is that possible? What am I missing here?

```
{
    "id": "cell: chris-VirtualBoxCell01",
    "name": "cell: chris-VirtualBoxCell01",
    "data": {},
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "node: chris-VirtualBoxNode01",
            "name": "node: chris-VirtualBoxNode01",
            "data": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "applicationServer: C4Cluster_server1",
                    "name": "applicationServer: C4Cluster_server1",
                    "data": {},
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "nodeAgent: nodeAgent",
                    "name": "nodeAgent: nodeAgent",
                    "data": {},
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "deploymentManagerNode: chris-VirtualBoxCellManager01",
            "name": "deploymentManagerNode: chris-VirtualBoxCellManager01",
            "data": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "deploymentManager: deploymentManager",
                    "name": "deploymentManager: deploymentManager",
                    "data": {},
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the snippet that should be of interest:

```
//Get JSON from Grails domain model
JSON json = ServerNode.findAll ("from ServerNode as s where s.root=true") as JSON;
//check result
System.out.println (json);
//turn into a JSONObject by chopping off surrounding []
String jsonString = json.toString ().substring (1, json.toString ().length ()-1);
//check result
System.out.println (jsonString);
//render to JSONObject
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject (jsonString);

//modify structure a little more        
JSONObject finalJson = modifyJson (jObject);

//check the final form (produces the above output)  
System.out.println (finalJson);

//turn into string and print --> returns null       
String jString = finalJson.toString ();
System.out.println (jString);
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Could you share some code.